# Base Directory changes when a slash is added to URL

Tags: php, html

I have a standard PhP website with a 3 files and a stylesheet for each one of those, inside a style folder.
The files are these:

```
header.php
index.php
footer.php
```

I've made it as such so i can easily call the header and footer onto any page as i require it.

My problem is that, if i add a forward slash to the end of the URL, it changes the base folder, causing the stylesheet file to not be found as showed in the images attached.
Basically, it starts looking for "style/header.css" inside of the index folder, which doesnt even exist, hence can't find the CSS file, if i am understanding it correctly. I have an htaccess file to remove the .php extensions from the URL, but i tried without it and got the same error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/brf4l.jpg

I have read that using a absolute paths will help, but this is not going to be hosted anywhere so i'm not entirely sure how it will help my case.

This is the head tag on my header, which includes all the links

```
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="website" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo/logo3.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/header.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/extras.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/footer.css" />
  <script src="js/header.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b076d05399.js"></script>
</head>
```

And i simply use these codes to call upon the header and footer accordingly.

```
<?php
require_once "header.php";
?>

content

<?php
require_once "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Use require relative to the doc root or the absolute filesystem path, e.g. `require_once '/var/www/html/header.php';` (though you'd normally use some sort of config variable to define to path to root for portability).

Comment: I would like to maintain portability, because i will have to send the files over to my professor. What sort of config variables can i use?

Comment: There are *many* ways to set up config variables - simplest thing in your case might be to just use the default Apache environment variable for the docroot, something like `require_once $_SERVER['DOC_ROOT'] . '/header.php';` - it's not terribly sophisticated but it should do the job (assuming *header.php* is at the docroot).

Comment: Interesting. I will look into config variables some more and see if I can come up with a solution to my problem. I appreciate your comment and thankyou for your help!